# Firebase function not deploying in chosen region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I followed the steps mentioned  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region)
But it is not working.

My couldFunction code looks like the following:

```
const rf = functions.region('europe-west2');

exports.check = rf.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
  
})
```

When I go and deploy it using :

> firebase deploy --only functions

I get error in console

> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

It deploys fine when I remove the region, but it goes to uscentral-1 which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations)

With that code, it worked for me :

```
exports.check = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
  
})
```

Please note that you have to be in [the tarification level 1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) to use the europe-west2 region.

Comment: Can't use import statement. It throws error in my case> Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (Fatal)

Comment: I think the import is not the important part here. You can keep using the way you imported your functions. What is relevent is more the tarification part.

Comment: I was prompted to use Blaze Plan which I did. Is there something more to it?

Comment: Blaze Plan should be OK. I'm currently using the Blaze Plan with this exact code i posted, and everything was deployed fine.
Do you have any more error to display than just `Error: Functions did not deploy properly.` ?

Comment: No unfortunately. The CLI shows this error only. Works fine without the region.

Comment: I re-initialised firebase in my project and now it works!